# How to solve the following problem by using Gaussian elimination with partial pivoting (A=PLU)?

Tags: numerical-analysis

****The [Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zW5gj.png) is here***** (in the link)

Given a nonsingular matrix A $\in$ $R^*(nxn)$, how would you solve the following problems efficiently using Gaussian elimination with partial pivoting (the same as A = PLU)?

(a) Compute $\alpha$ = $c^T$(A^-1) b, where c, b $\in$ $R^n$

(b) Solve AX = B, where X, B $\in$ $R^*(nxm)$

---

for (a), I have no idea on what the equation is and
for (b), I solve as the following but I am not sure does it applied to all X where it can be come from any n x m matrix

AX=b, PLUX=b, LUX=P^(-1)b, Ly = P^(-1)b where Ux = y.

So can anyone tell me how to solve (a) and verify my answer for (b)? Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to credit the original source where you encountered this exercise.

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.   Also, please ask only one questin per post.

Comment: Strikingly similar: [How to solve the following problem by using Gaussian elimination with partial pivoting (A=PLU)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3472188).